# ¿Cómo mostrar info de un archivo json en html?

Tags: javascript, php, json

Mi consulta es ya que estoy tratando de hace una página web que básicamente va ser controlada por la base de datos, es decir tengo una tabla del item que quiero que se muestre y desde allí consulto algunos datos como el nombre y el path de la fotografía, cuando ya que tengo esta información la muestro con etiquetas de html y en una de estas etiquetas con ayuda del atributo `id` creo un identificador con los datos obtenidos anteriormente y quiero crear una funcion en javascript que va a leer la información del JSON y la va a mostrar.

Esta función tendría de parámetro el id de la etiqueta ya que justamente a este id lo he preparado para que tenga el path del documento JSON que estará alojado en una carpeta y que mediante el atributo `onload` de la etiqueta planeo que cuando se muestre el item también se muestre la información que se encuentra en el archivo.

esto es lo que tengo en el html aunque no lo he intado ejecutar ya que primero estoy buscando información sobre el atributo `onload` y si retiro el argumento de la función:

```
<ul id="CB_<?php echo $prod['DESCRIPCION_PRODUCTO'] ?>" onload="javascript: caractBrv(<?php echo $prod['DESCRIPCION_PRODUCTO'] ?>)"></ul>
```

en otras palabras estoy construyendo y mostrando los items según los datos que hay en la tabla y mientras que se muestran los datos de la tabla a su vez quiero que una función lea la información que se encuentra en un archivo JSON y que la muestre

Answer (score 1):

Cree una variable que va a contener la lista de todos los items de la clase lista,  mediante un bucle for fui leyendo la id de cada item y de igual manera utilizando una variable que especifica el path de la ubicación del archivo json y utilizando el XMLHttpRequest y pasandole la variable que tiene el path ya pude leer la informacion de cada item y observarla en consola.

```
window.onload = function() {
   var test = document.querySelectorAll('.listaBreves');
   for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
      let aux = test[i].id;
      const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.open('GET',aux,true);
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
         var resI = "";
         if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var datos = JSON.parse(this.response);
            for(i in datos.breves){
               resI += datos.breves[i];
            }
            console.log(resI);
         }
      }
      xhttp.send();
   }
}
```

Para mostrar en pantalla o mejor dicho en un elemento de html afuera del bucle `if` se procedera a mostrar mediante `document.getElementById().innerHTML = resI`

```
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var datos = JSON.parse(this.response);
    for(i in datos.breves){
        resI += datos.breves[i];
    }
}
document.getElementById(nom).innerHTML = resI;
```

y continua el cierre de la funcion que se llama en "onreadystatechange", por último el `xhttp.send()` y el cierre de la funcion llamada en el `window.onload`